# How to save and restore a tf.estimator.Estimator model with export_savedmodel?

Tags: tensorflow-estimator

I started using Tensorflow recently and I try to get use to tf.estimator.Estimator objects. I would like to do something a priori quite natural: after having trained my classifier, i.e. an instance of tf.estimator.Estimator (with the `train` method), I would like to save it in a file (whatever the extension) and then reload it later to predict the labels for some new data. Since the official documentation recommends to use Estimator APIs, I guess something as important as that should be implemented and documented.

I saw on some other page that the method to do that is `export_savedmodel` (see [the official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator#export_savedmodel)) but I simply don't understand the documentation. There is no explanation of how to use this method. What is the argument `serving_input_fn`? I never encountered it in the [Creating Custom Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators) tutorial or in any of the tutorials that I read. By doing some googling, I discovered that around a year ago the estimators where defined using an other class (`tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`) and it looks like the tf.estimator.Estimator is reusing some of the previous APIs. But I don't find clear explanations in the documentation about it.

Could someone please give me a toy example? Or explain me how to define/find this `serving_input_fn`?

And then how would be load the trained classifier again?

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:** I discovered that one doesn't necessarily need to use export_savemodel to save the model. It is actually done automatically. Then if we define later a new estimator having the same model_dir argument, it will also automatically restore the previous estimator, as explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints).

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, estimator automatically saves an restores the model for you during the training. export_savemodel might be useful if you want to deploy you model to the field (for example providing the best model for Tensorflow Serving).

Here is a simple example:

```
est.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base=FLAGS.export_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
```

`def serving_input_fn():
    inputs = {'features': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 3])}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)`

Basically serving_input_fn is responsible for replacing dataset pipelines with a placeholder. In the deployment you can feed data to this placeholder as the input to your model for inference or prediction.