# Getting wrong prediction after loading a saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save an `Estimator` and then load it to predict as required. Part where I train the model:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=bag_of_words_model)

# Train
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"words": x_train},  # x_train is 2D numpy array of shape (26, 5)
    y=y_train,                   # y_train is 1D panda series of length 26
    batch_size=1000,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=300)
```

I then save the model as follows:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(None, 5), name='words')
    receiver_tensors = {"predictor_inputs": serialized_tf_example}
    features = {"words": tf.tile(serialized_tf_example, multiples=[1, 1])}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

full_model_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="E:/models/",
                                              serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

I now load the model and give the test set to it for prediction:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

classifier = predictor.from_saved_model("E:\\models\\1547122667")
predictions = classifier({'predictor_inputs': x_test})
print(predictions)
```

This gives me predictions like:

```
{'class': array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15,  0,
        0,  5,  0, 20,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int64),
'prob': array([[9.9397606e-01, 6.5355714e-05, 2.2225287e-05, ..., 1.4510043e-07,
            1.6920333e-07, 1.4865007e-07],
           [9.9886864e-01, 1.4976941e-06, 7.0847680e-05, ..., 9.4182191e-08,
            1.1828639e-07, 9.5683227e-08],
           [9.9884748e-01, 2.1105163e-06, 1.1994909e-05, ..., 8.3957858e-08,
            1.0476184e-07, 8.5592234e-08],
           ...,
           [9.6145850e-01, 6.9048328e-05, 1.1446012e-04, ..., 7.3761731e-07,
            8.8173107e-07, 7.3824998e-07],
           [9.7115618e-01, 2.9716679e-05, 5.9592247e-05, ..., 2.8933655e-07,
            3.4183532e-07, 2.9737942e-07],
           [9.7387028e-01, 6.9163914e-05, 1.5800977e-04, ..., 1.6116818e-06,
            1.9025001e-06, 1.5990496e-06]], dtype=float32)}
```

`class` and `prob` are two things that I am predicting. Now, if I predict the output with the same test set without saving and loading the model:

```
# Predict.
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"words": x_test}, y=y_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=test_input_fn)
print(predictions)
```

then I get the output as follows:

```
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9023646e-01, 2.6038184e-05, 3.9950578e-06, ..., 1.3950405e-08,
       1.5713249e-08, 1.3064114e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 1, 'prob': array([2.0078469e-05, 9.9907070e-01, 8.9245419e-05, ..., 6.6533559e-08,
       7.1365662e-08, 6.8764685e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 2, 'prob': array([3.0828053e-06, 9.6484597e-05, 9.9906868e-01, ..., 5.9190391e-08,
       6.0995028e-08, 6.2322023e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 3, 'prob': array([7.4923842e-06, 1.1112734e-06, 1.1697492e-06, ..., 4.4295877e-08,
       4.4563325e-08, 4.0475427e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 4, 'prob': array([4.6085161e-03, 2.8403942e-05, 2.0638861e-05, ..., 7.6083229e-09,
       8.5255349e-09, 6.7836012e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 5, 'prob': array([6.2119620e-06, 7.2357750e-07, 2.6231232e-06, ..., 7.4999367e-09,
       9.0847436e-09, 7.5630142e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 6, 'prob': array([4.4882968e-06, 2.2007227e-06, 8.3352124e-06, ..., 2.3130213e-09,
       2.3657243e-09, 2.0045692e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 7, 'prob': array([1.88617545e-04, 9.01482690e-06, 1.47353385e-05, ...,
       3.38567552e-09, 3.97709154e-09, 3.37017392e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 8, 'prob': array([1.9843496e-06, 4.5909755e-06, 4.8804057e-05, ..., 2.2636470e-08,
       2.0094852e-08, 2.0215294e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 9, 'prob': array([2.5907659e-04, 4.4661370e-05, 6.9490757e-06, ..., 1.6249915e-08,
       1.7579131e-08, 1.5439820e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 10, 'prob': array([3.6456138e-05, 7.5861579e-05, 3.0208937e-05, ..., 2.7859956e-08,
       2.5423596e-08, 2.8662368e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 11, 'prob': array([1.1723863e-05, 9.1407037e-06, 4.8835855e-04, ..., 2.3693143e-08,
       2.0524153e-08, 2.3223269e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 12, 'prob': array([1.2886175e-06, 2.6652628e-05, 2.7812246e-06, ..., 4.8295210e-08,
       4.4282604e-08, 4.7342766e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 13, 'prob': array([3.3486103e-05, 1.3361238e-05, 3.6493871e-05, ..., 2.2195401e-09,
       2.4768412e-09, 2.0150714e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 14, 'prob': array([4.6108948e-05, 3.0377207e-05, 2.0945006e-06, ..., 4.2276231e-08,
       5.2376720e-08, 4.4969173e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 15, 'prob': array([1.7165689e-04, 2.9350400e-05, 3.2283624e-05, ..., 7.1849078e-09,
       7.6871531e-09, 6.6224697e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 16, 'prob': array([5.9876328e-07, 3.0931276e-06, 1.5760432e-05, ..., 4.0450086e-08,
       4.2720632e-08, 4.6017195e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 17, 'prob': array([2.6658317e-04, 9.9656281e-05, 4.0355867e-06, ..., 1.2873563e-08,
       1.4808875e-08, 1.2155732e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 18, 'prob': array([1.4914459e-04, 2.1025437e-06, 1.2505146e-05, ..., 9.8899635e-09,
       1.1115599e-08, 8.9312255e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 19, 'prob': array([2.5615416e-04, 2.3750392e-05, 2.2886352e-04, ..., 3.9635733e-08,
       4.5139984e-08, 3.8605780e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 20, 'prob': array([6.3949975e-04, 2.3652929e-05, 7.8577641e-06, ..., 2.0959168e-09,
       2.5495863e-09, 2.0428985e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 21, 'prob': array([8.2179489e-05, 8.4409467e-06, 5.4756888e-06, ..., 2.2360982e-09,
       2.4820561e-09, 2.1206517e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 22, 'prob': array([3.9681905e-05, 2.4394642e-06, 8.9102805e-06, ..., 2.0282410e-08,
       2.1132811e-08, 1.8368105e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 23, 'prob': array([3.0794261e-05, 6.5104805e-06, 3.3528936e-06, ..., 2.0360846e-09,
       1.9360573e-09, 1.7195430e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 24, 'prob': array([3.4596618e-05, 2.2907707e-06, 2.5318438e-06, ..., 1.1038886e-08,
       1.2148775e-08, 9.9556408e-09], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 25, 'prob': array([1.4846727e-03, 1.9189476e-06, 5.3232620e-06, ..., 3.1966723e-09,
       3.5612517e-09, 3.0947123e-09], dtype=float32)}
```

which is correct. Notice the difference between two outputs is that the `class` in the second one is increasing 1 by 1 while the `class` in the first case shows 0s at most places.

Why is there a difference in the prediction? Am I saving the model in a wrong way?

Edit 1:

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330841/how-to-save-and-restore-a-tf-estimator-estimator-model-with-export-savedmodel), I came to know that `Estimator` readily saved the checkpoints if  the `model_dir` argument is given. And loads the same graph when the same `model_dir` is referred to. So I did this while saving the model:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=bag_of_words_model, model_dir="E:/models/")
```

I checked and found that checkpoints have been stored at `E:/models/`. Now, the part where I want to restore the model, I wrote:

```
# Added model_dir args
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=bag_of_words_model, model_dir="E:/models/")
# Predict.
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={WORDS_FEATURE: x_test}, y=y_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=test_input_fn)
```

The logs gave me:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'E:/models/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x0000028240FAB518>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
WARNING:tensorflow:From E:\ml_classif\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_queue_runner.py:62: QueueRunner.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
WARNING:tensorflow:From E:\ml_classif\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_functions.py:500: add_queue_runner (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2019-01-14 19:17:51.157091: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from E:/models/model.ckpt-100
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
WARNING:tensorflow:From E:\ml_classif\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py:804: start_queue_runners (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

which show that the model has been successfully reconstructed from the given `model_dir`. I then try to predict the output on the test data but only to get the same output as the previous one:

```
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.8720157e-01, 1.9098983e-04, 8.6194178e-04, ..., 9.8885458e-08,
       1.0560690e-07, 1.1116919e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9646854e-01, 7.3993037e-06, 1.6678940e-03, ..., 3.3662158e-08,
       3.7401023e-08, 3.9902886e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9418157e-01, 2.2869966e-05, 7.2757481e-04, ..., 7.2877960e-08,
       8.5308180e-08, 8.7949694e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.8990846e-01, 2.0035572e-05, 5.0557905e-04, ..., 4.2098847e-08,
       4.6305473e-08, 4.8882491e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.3541616e-01, 1.6300696e-03, 2.8230180e-03, ..., 3.4934112e-07,
       3.5947951e-07, 3.8610020e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 5, 'prob': array([4.5955207e-04, 3.9533910e-04, 2.9366053e-04, ..., 6.4991447e-08,
       6.5079021e-08, 6.8886770e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.2468429e-01, 4.9159536e-04, 9.2872838e-03, ..., 1.0636869e-06,
       1.1284576e-06, 1.1437518e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.5501184e-01, 2.6409564e-04, 3.8474586e-03, ..., 1.4077391e-06,
       1.4964197e-06, 1.4892942e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.4813752e-01, 2.7400412e-04, 2.2020808e-03, ..., 2.9592795e-06,
       3.0286824e-06, 3.0610188e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.6341538e-01, 3.4047980e-04, 2.0810752e-03, ..., 6.5900326e-07,
       6.7539651e-07, 7.0834898e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9541759e-01, 7.4490390e-06, 3.9836011e-04, ..., 5.1197322e-08,
       5.6648332e-08, 5.9212919e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9666804e-01, 1.2600798e-05, 3.1346193e-04, ..., 3.9119975e-08,
       4.3912351e-08, 4.7076494e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9582565e-01, 2.3773579e-05, 5.5219355e-04, ..., 8.2924736e-08,
       9.1671566e-08, 9.3954029e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.4328243e-01, 1.5643415e-04, 3.1944674e-03, ..., 3.9115656e-07,
       4.2140312e-07, 4.4074648e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9599898e-01, 1.3793178e-05, 6.0236652e-04, ..., 1.1893864e-07,
       1.3845128e-07, 1.4301372e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 15, 'prob': array([1.8115035e-03, 1.0454544e-03, 2.0831774e-03, ..., 4.5647434e-06,
       5.0818121e-06, 4.9641203e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9594927e-01, 9.6870117e-06, 3.7690319e-04, ..., 1.1332005e-07,
       1.2312253e-07, 1.3208249e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.4268161e-01, 7.6396938e-04, 3.4147443e-03, ..., 5.8237259e-07,
       5.8584078e-07, 5.9859877e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 18, 'prob': array([1.2369211e-03, 7.1954611e-03, 3.4218519e-03, ..., 1.6767866e-06,
       1.5141470e-06, 1.5795833e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.9327940e-01, 2.4744159e-05, 8.3286857e-04, ..., 8.1387967e-08,
       9.2638246e-08, 9.4754824e-08], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 18, 'prob': array([4.3461438e-02, 7.7443835e-03, 1.0502382e-02, ..., 6.1044288e-06,
       6.4804617e-06, 6.6003668e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.1440409e-01, 2.1251327e-04, 1.9904026e-03, ..., 9.9065488e-08,
       1.0103827e-07, 1.0984956e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 5, 'prob': array([4.2783137e-02, 1.3115143e-02, 1.6208552e-02, ..., 3.9897031e-06,
       3.9228212e-06, 4.1420644e-06], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.0668356e-01, 6.9979503e-04, 4.9138898e-03, ..., 4.2717656e-07,
       4.3982755e-07, 4.7387920e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.3811822e-01, 1.6991694e-04, 2.0085643e-03, ..., 3.8740203e-07,
       4.0521365e-07, 4.3191656e-07], dtype=float32)}
{'class': 0, 'prob': array([9.5434970e-01, 2.1576983e-04, 2.3911290e-03, ..., 7.2219399e-07,
       7.4783770e-07, 7.9287622e-07], dtype=float32)}
```

Most of the classes are again `0`. Why is this happening? Is there any alternative that could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer. The model was saved and loaded correctly. The problem was that the `x_test` which I was passing to the prediction with saving/loading and without saving/loading was different (I know, I am really sorry for this mistake). The `x_test` w/o saving/loading the model had values +1 than the `x_test` w/ saving/loading. This was suggested to me by a `tensorflow` developer on github where I had opened up the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24857).

Comment: The only thing I am wondering right now is that you asked it, set a bounty and accepted your own answer as a solution, so do you get the bounty back?

Somehow you must have gotten a few new badges as well by answering your own question. Pretty interesting Pranjal

Comment: @AmitAmola No, the bounty is non-refundable. Also, accepting your own answer does not give you reputation or badges.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from Edit 1. According to TF documentation :

> Checkpointing Frequency
>   By default, the Estimator saves checkpoints in the model_dir according to the following schedule:
>
> Writes a checkpoint every 10 minutes (600 seconds).
>   Writes a checkpoint when the train method starts (first iteration) and completes (final iteration).
>   Retains only the 5 most recent checkpoints in the directory.
>   You may alter the default schedule by taking the following steps:
>
> Create a tf.estimator.RunConfig object that defines the desired schedule.
>   When instantiating the Estimator, pass that RunConfig object to the Estimator's config argument.

Did you let your train properly finished ? According to the log it doesn't seem so (since you restored model-ckpt100 and not model-ckpt300) .

If the experiment didn't take too long , I'll suggest you to delete the content of your saved model , and either let the training finish at the number of steps you defined when calling `classifier.train` , or as suggested by the documentation to create a tf.estimator.RunConfig that you pass as argument to the estimator and decide when to save.

I hope this will help you !

Comment: `model-ckpt100` was loaded because the I have set `steps=100` in the training. That is why `model-ckpt300` wasn't generated.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of wrong predictions is forgetting to standardize the input in the same way that the training/validation data was.

For example, if you standardized your training set by subtracting the mean and dividing by the variance, and you don't do the same thing with the data that you want predictions for, then the predictions will be nonsense. A good clue that this is happening is that the predictions will be extremely high or extremely low values.